# How can I make this code to find a pair with a sum more efficient?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I'm doing [this](http://www.testdome.com/Questions/Java/TwoSum/745?testId=27&testDifficulty=Easy) test on testdome.com for fun, and it's failing the efficiency test. What better way is there? I'm not counting any values twice. It seems the only way to do this is by brute force, which is an n^2 algorithm.

Here are the directions for the problem:

> Write a function that, given a list and a target sum, returns
>   zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to
>   the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should
>   return null.
>
> For example, findTwoSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12) should return
>   any of the following tuples of indices:
>    1, 4 (3 + 9 = 12),
>    2, 3 (5 + 7 = 12),
>    3, 2 (7 + 5 = 12) or
>    4, 1 (9 + 3 = 12).

And here's my code:

```
public class TwoSum {
public static int[] findTwoSum(int[] list, int sum) {
    if (list == null || list.length < 2) return null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) { //lower indexed element
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) { //higher indexed element
            if (list[i] + list[j] == sum) {
                return new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }
    }

    //none found  
    return null;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] indices = findTwoSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
    System.out.println(indices[0] + " " + indices[1]);
}
```

}

EDIT: So here's my final working code. Thanks everyone!

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TwoSum {
    public static int[] findTwoSum(int[] list, int sum) {
        if (list == null || list.length < 2) return null;
        //map values to indexes
        Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            indexMap.put(list[i], i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            int needed = sum - list[i];
            if (indexMap.get(needed) != null) {
                return new int[]{i, indexMap.get(needed)};
            }
        }

        //none found
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] indices = findTwoSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
        System.out.println(indices[0] + " " + indices[1]);
    }
}
```

As per Kon's suggestion, in one pass:

```
public static int[] findTwoSum(int[] list, int sum) {
    if (list == null || list.length < 2) return null;
    //map values to indexes
    Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        int needed = sum - list[i];
        if (indexMap.get(needed) != null) {
            return new int[]{i, indexMap.get(needed)};
        }

        indexMap.put(list[i], i);
    }

    //none found
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are doing this in the naive way. As you say, this will give you a solution in `n^2` time. It is possible to get a solution in linear time. The solution uses a very popular data structure. Can you think about that and get somewhere?

Comment: hmm... Thanks for the tip, I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: Please feel free to ask clarifying questions here. This is a very popular interview question (I've asked it myself many times) so it's good to "discover" the solution on your own as you'll learn it better that way.

Comment: OTOH, OP's code is very clear and understandable.  I'm interested in seeing how clear he can make the fast code.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the array being ordered? It didn't say it would be. Would it be better to put the elements in something like a binary search tree?

Comment: @yts Solving it when the array is ordered is simpler, but in this case it can still be done it linear time whether it's sorted or not.

Comment: I can't figure it out :( Time to buy meself a good algorithm/data structure book.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a dictionary?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz A Map? Sure.

Comment: @yts no need for a book, there are a million examples of this problem solved online. Just google for "Pairs to a sum" or something similar

Comment: @Kon Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime. :)

Comment: @yts fair enough, but the internet has every fish you'll ever learn to catch :) Good luck! Please come back if you need help implementing/understanding the solution.

Comment: @Kon Soo you'll let me search the internet during an interview? :P Or did you mean to say the internet can teach me so let the trees live? I put my final code in the question.

Comment: @yts yes, internet will teach you these things. Books are nice, but I've learned everythign online. It's a style choice thing.

Comment: @yts One more thought: Your new code is great. Way faster than the old code. But it can still be faster. You can do it in ONE pass of the array. Can you think of how to do it? (Hint: The algorithm is the same)

Comment: good point. Updated :)

Comment: This is a very subtle change that optimizes for large input in the way you set up the map.  It is funny that other O(n) solutions fail, without thinking to save time in init, because the other solutions are presented as correct for interview in more than one book.

Comment: Just one more thing: To play it safe 'sum' should be 'long' to account for int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue. Just my 2c.

Comment: And another thing: "returns zero-based *indices* of *any* two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum (solutions at the time of this writing return *only* the first match found which is NOT exactly what we want here) I have posted my solution down below written in C#. It should be easy enough to convert it over to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you do in the inner loop, your checking if list[i] + list[j] == sum.

If you transform the equation slightly, it means given list[i] and sum (which are both constants within the inner loop), you are really asking "is there an index where the value (sum - list[i]) is stored", and thats what your inner loop solves.

Now applying the knowledge that you could solve the problem using essentially a indexOf(sum - list[i])-style method in linear time, there are data structures that can answer this kind of question in better time than O(N).

Comment: updated question to show my code. You gave me the amount of info I was looking for.

Comment: @yts Wow, that looks exactly like what I was thinking of :P Are you sure you haven't read my mind? Glad you could figure it out.

Comment: :) not telling (this is filler text to make my comment at least 15 characters in length)

Answer (score 1):

Here is **linear solution** (save sorting which is O(n*log(n)) ):
**1)** Sort your initial array a[]
**2)** let i be the first index of a[], and j - the last

```
i = 0;
j = a[].length - 1;
```

**3)** lets move from two ends:

```
do{
  if(a[i]+a[j] < sum)
    i++;
  else if(a[i]+a[j] > sum)
    j--;
  else { // we have found required indexes!
     put (i, j) to result set;
     i++;
  }
} while(i < j);
```

The final result - set of pairs (i,j) that give required sum. 
You can stop after first pair and return it.

**P.S.** if you have array like {3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9} this solution will not give all the combinations:)

Comment: Hmm..that looks interesting. Was about to say sorting is n*log(n) but you beat me to it :) Durandal's solution is linear and more intuitive for me so I went with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> findTwoSum(int[] list, int sum) {
    if (list == null || list.length < 2) return null;
    Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> arrayResult = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        indexMap.put(list[i], i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        int needed = sum - list[i];
        if (indexMap.get(needed) != null) {
            arrayResult.put(i, indexMap.get(needed));
        }
    }
    return arrayResult.isEmpty()?null:arrayResult;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> indices = findTwoSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
    System.out.println(indices);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution written in C#. It should be easy enough to convert it over to Java lingo:

```
static public IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> FindAllTwoSumIndexes(IList<int> list, long desiredSum)
{
    var count = list?.Count;
    if (list == null || count <= 1)
        return null;

    var results = new List<Tuple<int, int>>(32);
    var indexesMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, List<int>>(); //0 value-to-indexes
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var thisValue = list[i];
        var needed = desiredSum - thisValue;
        if (indexesMap.TryGetValue(needed, out var indexes))
        {
            results.AddRange(indexes.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x, i)));
        }

        indexesMap.AddOrUpdate(
            key: thisValue,
            addValueFactory: x => new List<int> { i },
            updateValueFactory: (x, y) =>
            {
                y.Add(i);
                return y;
            }
        );
    }

    return results.Any() ? results.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2).ToList() : null;

    //0 bare in mind that the same value might be found over multiple indexes   we need to take this into account
    //  also note that we use concurrentdictionary not for the sake of concurrency or anything but because we like
    //  the syntax of the addorupdate method which doesnt exist in the simple dictionary
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Java program which find the pair of values in the array whose sum is equal to k using Hashtable or Set in the most efficient way.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArraySumUsingSet {

public static void main(String args[]) {
   prettyPrint(getRandomArray(9), 11);
   prettyPrint(getRandomArray(10), 12);
}

/**
 * Given an array of integers finds two elements in the array whose sum is equal to n.
 * @param numbers
 * @param n
 */
public static void printPairsUsingSet(int[] numbers, int n){
    if(numbers.length < 2){
        return;
    }        
    Set set = new HashSet(numbers.length);

    for(int value : numbers){
        int target = n - value;

        // if target number is not in set then add
        if(!set.contains(target)){
            set.add(value);
        }else {
            System.out.printf("(%d, %d) %n", value, target);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Utility method to find two elements in an array that sum to k.
 */
public static void prettyPrint(int[] random, int k){
    System.out.println("Random Integer array : " + Arrays.toString(random));
    System.out.println("Sum : " + k);
    System.out.println("pair of numbers from an array whose sum equals " + k);
    printPairsUsingSet(random, k);
}

/**
 * Utility method to return random array of Integers in a range of 0 to 15
 */
public static int[] getRandomArray(int length){
    int[] randoms = new int[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        randoms[i] = (int) (Math.random()*15);
    }
    return randoms;
}

}
```

### Output

```
Random Integer array : [0, 14, 0, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 7]
Sum : 11
pair of numbers from an array whose sum equals 11
(7, 4)
(3, 8)
(7, 4)
Random Integer array : [10, 9, 5, 9, 0, 10, 2, 10, 1, 9]
Sum : 12
pair of numbers from an array whose sum equals 12
(2, 10)
```