# Volatile variables and the use of synchronization blocks

Tags: java

Is it correct to say that a volatile primitive:

1) Needs synchronization for non-atomic operations
2) Doesn't need synchronization for atomic operations, like the following:

```
volatile bool selector;
selector = true;
```

Comment: `bool` is C++; `boolean` is Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply reassigning the volatile variable, it shouldn't require synchronization. That's the idea behind them.

Actually, in this case it wouldn't even have to be volatile because the new value `true` doesn't depend on the old value of `selector` so it wouldn't matter if it has been changed by another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Oracle Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile
>   (including long and double variables).

The value/purpose of using a volatile declaration is the same as using a `synchronize` block. So no, you don't need to sync access to a volatile variable

As far as the trade-off between the two, the same documentation says:

> Using simple atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing
>   these variables through synchronized code, but requires more care by
>   the programmer to avoid memory consistency errors. Whether the extra
>   effort is worthwhile depends on the size and complexity of the
>   application.

Comment: For a good minute I was confused by your icon/name, when the heck did I answer this question :)

Comment: @Durandal Haha! When I saw Durandal had given another answer for this question, I was sure I had communicated with him recently, but I couldn't find it anywhere in his history! [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066986/how-can-i-make-this-short-code-more-efficient-sum-pairs) what I'm talking about

Comment: @Durandal Wow, pretty low odds of a Marathon fan collision but we managed to do it!